# Lightswitch with RIA service migration problems

Tags: service, wcf-ria-services, ria, visual-studio-lightswitch

we have migrated LS solution developed with VS2010 to VS2012. After the migration the strange problem appears with WCF RIA service that was working just fine with VS2010. WCF RIA service connects to database and gets the data using stored procedure. And this is working fine in LS screen, I mean the data are shown as accepted. I can update records, but after I click on "Save" button the conflict dialog appears saying,"A single resource was expected for the result but multiple resources were found" error in  lightswitch 2012 WCF RIA service and othertimes we got another error  as "unable to save the data - DataService 'user information'(RIA service name) has changes that will not be saved.To modify the collection of data service that can be saved. Implement the 'Initializedataworkspace' method".

Please help me on this...